# Finding associated words to a named entity

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

Is there a way to find a list of associated words to a Named Entity?

For instance : let the Named Entity be FIFA. Now FIFA is a Football Organization and hence related to the term football and all the terms related to football like jersey, footballers, goal, goalkeeper, halftime, penalty, freekick et cetera.

Is there a way we could do that? I have tried Babelnet but didn't get the desired results or anything even close to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to add a comment (not enough reputation points), so please do not consider this as an answer.

The closest I can recommended based on the question is to checkout out DBPedia Spotlight. Demo available here https://demo.dbpedia-spotlight.org/

You can also experiment by choosing the type of annotation required by modifying **Select Types option**